# NSDateFormatter: How to read dates in March

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

The NSDateFormatter can be used to construct NSDate instances from date strings.
This works except with date strings for March, where the MMM month format is used.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *aDate = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
[fmt release];
```

For example, the dateString value:

- @"29-Jan-2011" works
- @"04-Feb-2011" works
- @"20-Mar-2011" does not work! Resulting NSDate instance aDate is nil

Is this a bug in iOS SDK 4.3 or does the formatter expect a different abbreviation for March?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"20-Mar-2011";
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *aDate = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
[fmt release];
NSLog(@"date=%@", aDate);
```

Output:

```
2011-03-17 22:04:39.798 Untitled[18025:207] date=2011-03-20 04:00:00 +0000
```

Is it possible you have your locale set to something other than English?

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem. The locale on the simulator was set to German, where March is abbreviated as "Mär". Thanks!